# How to install only NoMachine player and not server

Tags: nomachine

I would like to have only NoMachine player on my local PC. The free edition. I don't want anyone connecting to my PC. For security reasons. For piece of mind.

I don't trust NoMachine that it doesn't run server too, despite I disabled it.

I disabled NoMachine server as per official recommendation:
[image]

However, server still gets started, and possibly active, as per Task Manager:
[image: Windows Task Manager screenshot clearly showing that NoMachine server is running]

And even worse, the NoMachine desktop Monitor even explicitly says: "Accepting connection is enabled". That is the very opposite what I want. How to stop it.
[image: NoMachine desktop Monitor showing Accepting connection is enabled]

Well, best to stop it by not installing server in the first place.

Installed version: nomachine_6.12.3_7.exe from https://www.nomachine.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a "Shutdown", not a "Stop" of the server.

If you want to "disable desktop sharing" you can simply do it by doing click on the "Accepting connection is enabled" in the !M monitor (in system tray).

If you want to shutdown the server, from the same monitor menu, choose "Close the NoMachine application". You will be asked if you want to run the NoMachine application at the next startup: choose 'No' to disable the automatic start of NoMachine services at boot time.

If you want to do it directly from the server settings, from the same monitor menu choose "Show the service status" and then select "Shutdown the server".

If the server is shut down, and told to not start at startup, nobody will be able to connect and nobody will be able to visualize your desktop, so "disabling desktop sharing" won't even be necessary because no process will be running after a shutdown.

Forgot to say... Consider also that there is the Enterprise Client available, that doesn't include any server software. Intended for the "Enterprises", as the name implies, but you can surely install as well. Maybe this fits your case better since you were asking about installing NoMachine player.

Comment: Enterprise Client that seems the way to go. Thank you. I didn't realize it is also free to download, install and connect. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I didn't do any "Shutdown" or "Stop" of the server. Where is that "Shutdown"? I just unchecked "Start automatic services at startup" in the server configuration nad restarted my PC. It had very little effect. It still does start server service despite is marked as "manual". Very confusing and rather off putting.

Comment: I double checked, I cannot see "Shutdown" anywhere. Only Stop/Start ad Restart. Do we have different verions?